# Problemas com injeção de dependêcias em testes unitários Angular

Tags: testes-de-unidade, injeção-de-dependência, jasmine, angular

Estou tentando realizar testes unitários no Angular, porém tenho alguns problemas com a injeção de dependências nos services. Na aplicação existem vários services que dependem um do outro, por exemplo:

1. Service A tem como dependência o Service B
2. Service B tem como dependência o Service C
3. Service C tem como dependência o Service D
4. Service D tem como dependência o HttpClient e o Router do Angular

Devido a esses múltiplos níveis de dependência não consigo realizar a injeção dos providers na classe de teste.
Foi levantada a possibilidade de criar mocks para os services, mas devido a quantidade de dependências seria necessário criar um mock para cada service.

Existe alguma maneira de facilitar a injeção de dependências nos services?

Comment: vc ta usando jest ou o karma?

Comment: Estou usando karma

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `useValue` ou `useClass` para usar algo que seria um *stub* ou um *mock* do seu serviço. Por exemplo, vamos supor que você tem um serviço que retorna um usuario via http:

```
providers:[{
     provide: SeuServico,
     useValue: { getUser: (userId) => of({ name: 'Joao', idade: 13 }) }
}]
```

Assim você tem um serviço que não tem nenhuma depedência, acabando com esse ciclo.